# Emptying string grid in Delphi

Tags: delphi, memory, grid

In Delphi, is there a fast way of emptying a TStringgrid (containing in excess of 5000 rows) that will also free the memory?

Setting the rowcount to 1, empties the grid but does not free the memory.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: What is the problem with the memory? Setting rowcount to 1 does not free the memory, but, according to me, this memory is used again when you refill the rows. If you really want to free the memory, free the TStringGrid an re-Create it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should uninitialize the allocated strings (from the string list where the row texts are stored). Cleaning is done by columns since you have a lot of rows.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to StringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
    StringGrid1.Cols[I].Clear;
  StringGrid1.RowCount := 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

By "does not free the memory", do you mean that if you set `RowCount := 1`, and then set the `RowCount := 10' you can still see the old content of the`Cells`?

If so, this is an old issue and has nothing to do with the memory not being freed; it's simply because you just happen to see the previous content of the memory when it's allocated again, because memory isn't zero'd out.

I have a pretty standard routine in a utility unit that deals with this visual glitch, and unless the grid is **huge** works fast enough. Just pass the `TStringGrid` *before* you change the `RowCount` or `ColCount` to a lower value.

```
procedure ClearStringGrid(const Grid: TStringGrid);
var
  c, r: Integer;
begin
  for c := 0 to Pred(Grid.ColCount) do
    for r := 0 to Pred(Grid.RowCount) do
      Grid.Cells[c, r] := '';
end;
```

Use it like this:

```
ClearStringGrid(StringGrid1);
StringGrid1.RowCount := 1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to call it vice versa ? First set the `RowCount` and then `ClearStringGrid` ? You're not locking the update by `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate` and it may flicker.

Comment: Actually, no. :) If you change the `RowCount` first, you don't have access to the old rows in order to clear them. You're right though about forgetting `Begin/EndUpdate`; my actual code is on a different machine, and I forgot them. Fixed. :)

Comment: There's no `TStringGrid.BeginUpdate` or `TStringGrid.EndUpdate` ;) But you can access either `Rows` or `Cols` and because OP said he has many rows I decided to clear `Cols`. And of course you're right, if you would set the `RowCount` first then you would iterate only once in rows.

Comment: You just *insist* I fix the `Begin/EndUpdate` thing, don't you? :) Got it; must have been really tired yesterday. <g> Thanks.

Comment: even `Items` [doesn't exists](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Grids.TStringGrid_Declared_Members) :) Only `Rows` and `Cols` which are `TStrings`. It's really poor control ;)

Comment: Fixed *again*. <g> Back to where it started.

Comment: Should use the Clear method in TLama's approach to ensure object references (if any) are also set to nil.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest storing your string values in your own memory that you have full control over, and then use a TDrawGrid, or better a virtual TListView, to display the contents of that memory as needed.

Comment: +1, or my favorite [VirtualTreeView](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) :)

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to use a TStringGrid is using OnGetValue/OnSetValue.
This way only the text of visible cells are requested dynamically.
Adding and removing rows is then lighting fast, otherwise TStringgrid is
very slooow when you have more than 5000 records.
This way I can fill and clear a grid with 700.000 records within a second!

Comment: Do you maybe know when Delphi introduced the `OnGetValue`/`OnSetValue` events? At least in Delphi 4 they are not available yet.

Answer (score 1):

When memory usage is the critical argument, consider using another grid. For example, [NLDStringGrid](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33481) that is (re)written by myself, and which has an additional property called `MemoryOptions`. It controls whether data can be stored beyond `ColCount * RowCount`, whether the storage is proportional (less memory usage for partially filled rows and columns), whether to store the `Cols` and `Rows` property results and whether the data is stored in sparse manner.

To clear such grid that has `moBeyondGrid` excluded from the memory options, setting `RowCount` to `FixedRows` suffices.

It's open source and downloadable [from here](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDStringGrid).